# Debug a LT3759 boost converter

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, boost

I wanted to make a 3V - 4.2V in to 5V/2A out boost converter.
I kind of copied the schematic of an [example board](https://www.digikey.com/reference-designs/en/ac-dc-and-dc-dc-conversion/dc-dc-smps-single-output/1594) on digikey.

I developped 2 pcb using this schematic (both have same connections/layout/components). On one it worked flawlessly. On the other one it did not. I tried to fix the bad one switching components of the good one but doing so both stopped working eventually. I tried to dispose every component of the converter and solder on a new one but still both did not work and react the same.

This is my schematic and layout. The layout is based on the recommanded layout of the datasheet.
[image]
[image]
I measured the voltage of each pin of the LT3759 using an oscilloscope while applying 3.5V at V_conv_in:

pin 1: 2.64V

pin 2: 1.20V

pin 3: 3.28V

pin 4: 0.6V (with disturbances).

pin 5: 0V

pin 6: 0V

pin 7: 0V

pin 8: 720mV

pin 9: 3.52 V

pin 10: 3.64V (with disturbances).

pin 11: 3.72 (with disturbances).

pin 12: 2.52

As for the disturbances: this is pin 4 measured:
[image]

Any advice on how to further debug the converter?
Page 8 of the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3759fc.pdf) shows the schematic of the internals of the converter.

Physical images of the converters:
[image: converter 1]
[image: converter 2]

Comment: So now you have two boards that don't work. Do you see where your fault finding error was?

Comment: Try removing all of the flux. I've seen flux short out power rails before.

Comment: @rdtsc I removed all the flux using PCC. Then I performed the same measurements and the results were the same

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, I probably should only have performed measurements on the working one... I keep it in mind for next time